# How to rename a file or folder in google drive using the api in php?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to make a function for renaming a file in google drive using the api:v2 in php. But every the function patch that is said to be used to rename the files does not exist in the drives file of google's in '\google\apiclient-services\src\Drive\Resource\Drives.php' file. I did search in other files but it was not there. Now how can I rename the files and folder in my drive. I did try to change some.

The code that I got from the documentation was:-

```
 /**
 * Rename a file.
 *
 * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param string $fileId ID of the file to rename.
 * @param string $newTitle New title for the file.
 * @return Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile The updated file. NULL is returned if
 *     an API error occurred.
 */
function renameFile($service, $fileId, $newTitle) {
    try {
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setTitle($newTitle);

    $updatedFile = $service->files->patch($fileId, $file, array(
        'fields' => 'title'
    ));

    return $updatedFile;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

The error it gives:

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile::setTitle() in .\GoogleDrive.php:153
Stack trace:
#0 .\test.php(22): GoogleDrive->renameFile('drive_Id_...', 'test2.txt')
#1 {main}
  thrown in .\GoogleDrive.php on line 153

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile::setTitle() in .\GoogleDrive.php:153
Stack trace:
#0 .\test.php(22): GoogleDrive->renameFile('drive_Id_...', 'test2.txt')
#1 {main}
  thrown in .\GoogleDrive.php on line 153
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was simple.

The fill code is:

```
 /**
 * Rename a file.
 *
 * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param string $fileId ID of the file to rename.
 * @param string $newTitle New title for the file.
 * @return Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile The updated file. NULL is returned if
 *     an API error occurred.
 */
function renameFile($service, $fileId, $newTitle) {
    try {
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setName($newTitle);

    $updatedFile = $service->files->update($fileId, $file);

    return $updatedFile;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

The parts the  you need to change are:

- Change the `->patch` to `->update` and `->setTitle` to `->setName`
- `array('fields' => 'title'));` You need to change remove this. This will give the error:

  ```
   An error occurred: {
   "error": {
       "errors": [{
           "domain": "global",
           "reason": "invalidParameter",
           "message": "Invalid field selection title",
           "locationType": "parameter",
           "location": "fields"
       }],
       "code": 400,
       "message": "Invalid field selection title"
   }
  ```

  }

This works on both file and folder.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive V3 PHP API documentation is sparse and cryptic.

To perform the same file rename operation using that version of the API:

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName($newTitle);
$updatedFile = $service->files->update($fileId, $file, array('fields' => 'name'));
```